# (Non-Conservative) Population Proportion Confidence Interval Solution Help Please

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion

I'm trying to solve this problem for an online practice exam, I can't come up with the same answer as the options given and I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong.

The question is asking for a 95% non-conservative confidence interval for a population proportion.
The following was given:

x = 460

n = 1368

I calculated the following:

phat = 460/1368 = 0.3362

standard error of phat = Square root of (phat*(1-phat))/n = 0.01

I used the z* table to find that z* = 1.96.

Because it's asking for the non-conservative confidence interval I used the following formula to calculate the confidence interval:

phat +/- z*standard error of phat

Lower = 0.3362 - 0.025 = 0.3112 = 31.52%

Upper = 0.3362 + 0.025 = 0.3613 = 36.13%

After all those calculations I thought I had the right answer, but this is not an option in the selections.  I'm given the following options to choose from:

31.07% to 36.19%

26.83% to 32.23%

28.30% to 30.76%

30.93% to 36.33%

And this is where I'm stumped.  I've double checked my numbers and formula several times and don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you for helping me figure this out!

Comment: Don't round your intermediate results.  In particular, your "0.01" errs substantially because the correct SE is $0.01277\ldots.$ which is over 25% greater.  Consider using a continuity correction, too.

Comment: @whuber thank you for the help - I'm using Excel for the intermediate result so while I typed in the rounded number, in the calculation it's using the 0.1277 number you show as displayed here: 1.96*0.01277=0.025

Comment: Then you will come close to just one of the answers--and much closer when you use a continuity correction.